# Aligning text to videos contained in iframes

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to put together a showcase for a series of videos and images. I've used the iframe code to embed the videos from Youtube but I keep running into issues with the videos not aligning vertically.

https://jsfiddle.net/aldo_rainn/0fcc841p/ (zoom out to 50% to see issue)

Is there any way to get the videos vertical, (to be on top of each other) aligned to the left of the page, and have descriptive text on their right sides?

```
<h3>Content Marketing</h3>
<iframe style="float:left" width="760" height="515" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4kEPRHIDltU?autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
<p>CNA Video Description of video Results: Combined reach of over 6,000 across multiple platforms</p>
<iframe style="float:left" width="760" height="515" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4bYbXGHlNrc?autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
<p>Description of video</p>
<img src="/images/EmailNursevueMarketing.jpg" alt="Nursesvue Email Marketing" style="width:600px; height:1500px; margin-left: 200px;">
<img src="/images/Winter Careertek Newsletter.jpg" alt="Email Newsletter" style="width:800px; height:1500px; margin-left: 200px;">
<p>I created and distributed a series of email promotions to potential students interested learning technical skills. Over 2000 people were reached within the first two months. </p>
```

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle or a codepen for that issue?

Comment: Just created a Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aldo_rainn/0fcc841p/

Comment: just add a wrapper to your tab content and give it a display flex. I made a change for your content marketing tab: https://jsfiddle.net/0fcc841p/1/